# DBSCAN clustering with haversine distance

Tags: python, dbscan, haversine

I have a dataset with 33707 rows. I want to cluster my dataset using DBSCAN clustering algorithm with haversine distance metrics. My code is given in the image. I am getting only one clusters. Which value should I change eps or min_samples to get accurate number of clusters.

```
kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
epsilon = 0.5 / kms_per_radian
model = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon,min_samples=300,algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(X))
class_predictions = model.labels_

df['CLUSTERS_DBSCAN']=class_predictions
```

Comment: Actually these two parameters control the number of cluster you obtain. Furthermore, how can we help you if we don't know your data? What is actually "the accurate number of clusters"? Maybe in this specific case all data points belong to a single cluster. Unless you provide at least some sample points and give more details about your problem, you won't get much help. 
As a first shot I will try decreasing the min_samples. Try with 100 and see what happens. Cluster analysis is an explorative technique, so you should try some parameters, analyse, try other params, analyse again, and so on...

Comment: @Dawid I am sorry. Actually i am new in this. I have got 13 clusters with eps=5 and min_sample=300. (the number of cluster is same as dbscan with euclidean distance) Is it wrong to take eps=5? 
I mean previously when i clustered my data via dbscan with euclidean distance I got 13 clusters with eps=0.5 and min_samples=300. But this value results in 1 cluster with the haversine matrix. I tried changing these two parameter and with eps=5.0 i get my target value of number of clusters. I just want to know whether it is okay to take eps value 5 or not. Kinda confused...

Comment: If you have two distinct distance measures, then it is not surprising that you obtain different clusterings (different amount of clusters). The epsilon is a parameter that is inextricably linked to a chosen distance measure. Consider a simple example: metric A has the range of values between 0 and 1, and metrc B between 0 and 1000. Now, does it make sense to try to find a single, unique value of epsilon?
There is no golden rule here that would say "5.721" is the best value of epsilon for all possible clusterings. You try one value, analyse what you get, try second value, analyse, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to decrease the min_samples to small number.